# Grammar/ Spelling check for daily routine

Tags: vocabulario, gramática, verbos, conjugación

I have written a small paragraph on my daily routine in Spanish and was wondering if anyone could just check that it flows well and there are no grammatical or spelling errors.

Todas las mañanas me despierto a las ocho menos cuarto pero no me levanto hasta las ocho en punto. Primero desayuno cereales, luego me preparo para la universidad. Salgo de casa y voy a la universidad en autobús a las nueve en punto. Yo estudio hasta la una y media cuando como sopa en la café vegetariano. Luego voy la biblioteca y continuo estudio hasta tarde. Normalmente  termino de estudio y vuelvo a mi casa sobre a las nueve de la tarde, pero a veces voy a el supermercado antes mi casa. Después ceno y veo la tele un rato. Por pongo el despertador y acuesto sobre la media noche.

Comment: Questions **asking for corrections in a text** e.g. "are there any mistakes in this text?" are off-topic. You can ask specific sentences in separate questions that may help other users. For more information, see what you can ask [here](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Todas las mañanas me despierto a las ocho menos cuarto ADD COMMA HERE pero no me levanto hasta las ocho en punto. Primero desayuno cereales, luego me preparo para la universidad. Salgo de casa y voy a la universidad en autobús a las nueve en punto. Yo DELETE "Yo" AS IT IS IMPLICIT ON THE VERB estudio hasta la una y media cuando como CHANGE "como" BY "tomo" sopa en la café CHANGE "la café" BY "la cafetería" OR "el café" vegetariano CHANGE "vegetariano" TO "vegetariana" IF YOU CHOSEN "la cafetería". Luego voy la biblioteca y continuo ADD ACCENT "continúo" estudio CHANGE "estudio" BY "estudiando" hasta tarde. Normalmente termino de estudio CHANGE "estudio" BY "estudiar" y vuelvo a mi casa sobre a las nueve de la tarde, pero a veces voy a el supermercado antes ADD "de ir a" mi casa. Después ceno y veo la tele un rato. Por pongo THIS MAKES NO SENSE, TRY "Pongo" el despertador y ADD "me" acuesto sobre la media noche CHANGE "media noche" BY "medianoche".